# Add text inside header nav prestashop

Tags: css, prestashop

I am using prestashop open source cart, and I want to add text on top next to my 'call us now: number'
[image]
I dont know how to add payment logos inside my footer next to my '@copyright:' below are some pictures of the desired outcome

[image]

Comment: You should tag your question with [tag:prestashop].

Comment: thank you for reply, but how i do it? thank you

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34073719/edit) link at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to edit your header.tpl file withing your theme.

i.e. www.yourshop/themes/yourtheme/header.tpl

SAQ

Comment: Thank you for reply Saq Storm, appreciated. Ok, on my header.tpl, where and how should i insert the text so it appears on headernav? Thank you again. If you want i can send the code of header.tpl. Regards, Dilshod

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on blockbanner, there is a hook in Prestashop called hookBanner, which is located just above header.

Editing header.tpl and footer.tpl can be useful, but first of all check documentation here :

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Theme+development+fundamentals

There are also useful HTML free modules, available on Prestashop forum (megablock, htmlblock...) or websites

Comment: Thank you Cyssoo for answer, but honestly i have tried almost everything. All i want to do is to insert FREE SHIPPING text next to my call us now77777777  on my header nav. But no idea

Comment: In header.tpl, you could try adding HTML above line 74 . However there is a module called blockcontact, you could find tpl there : /prestashop/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcontact/blockcontact.tpl. There is phone contact infos located in hook banner. Edit file and add your oown code just above line 37 (on Prestashop 1.6.1.3)