# Prestashop: how can i add text on header nav

Tags: prestashop

Sorry it's me again cause I have not solved the issue :(. Is there anybody that can help me solve this problem. I just want to add WORLDWIDE FREE SHIPPING text on my header nav next to call us now. I have tried to add text in nav.tpl file but, I could not. I'm posting image here to see.

Thank you
Regards
Dilshod

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In prestashop it has a blockpermanentlinks  module  which is use to show permanentlinks on  header so user this module and write all information on blockpermanentlinks-header.tpl  file.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but no result at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073719/add-text-inside-header-nav-prestashop